# asp.net production / development environments

Tags: asp.net, development-environment, production-environment

Most of my previous web applications have built using the pyramid (python) framework. With pyramid, it is possible to run the application in either development or production mode. This is achieved by providing the location of a production.ini or a development.ini settings file as one of the start up arguments to the application.

This file contains settings relating to logging levels, error reporting and database connections. The equivalent of these files in the .net world would appear to be web.config files. I assume i can create different execution environments, by simply creating a new web.config, renaming it to something appropriate, and restarting the application.

My question is, how can i get my app to target the correct *.config file (hypothetically call them production.config and development.config)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at [MSDeploy](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy).  I use this for similar situations and it's helped me establish a single parameters file (of what is to be replaced, regardless of if it's XML, a filepath, text file, etc.) and multiple set parameter files [you can read about declareParam and setParam [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569084%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Without knowing too much of your structure you are basically going to do something to the effect of this.

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:contentPath=c:\pathtosite\root -dest:package=c:\package.zip -declareParamFile=c:\packageparameters.xml"
```

Create an associated parameters file for each environment such as

```
development.xml
staging.xml
production.xml
```

([Here](http://twenty6-jc.blogspot.com/2010/09/msdeploy-and-declare-and-set-parameter.html) is a good explanation of parameter file setup)

then for your deploy you would have something (depending on the providers you want to use)

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=c:\package.zip -dest:contentPath=c:\inetpub\production -setParamFile=c:\<environment>.xml
```

The # of providers is pretty extensive.  Content Path is just an easy example, but you can pull directly from IIS, to IIS, etc.  Pretty robust.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way that I know of to specify a different web.config file.  Since .NET 4.0, however, you can use something called web.config transforms, which modify your base web.config on build.  You can have a Web.Debug.Config and Web.Release.Config, which get applied depending on which build configuration you're using.  Keep in mind these aren't normal web.config files, but rather **transform** files that modify the base web.config.

For more info and a walkthrough of the basic idea involved, see [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx).  The basic example given of a web.config transform file is this, which modifies a connection string to use a different connection string for the release build:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyDB" connectionString="ReleaseSQLServer" 
            xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```